# spring-data-redis cluster recovery issue

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

We're running a 7-node redis cluster, with all nodes as masters (no slave replication). We're using this as an in-memory cache, so we've commented out all saves in redis.conf, and we've got the following other non-defaults in redis.conf:

```
maxmemory: 30gb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
cluster-require-full-coverage no
```

The client for this cluster is a spring-boot rest api application, using spring-data-redis with jedis as the driver. We mainly use the spring caching annotations.

We had an issue the other day where one of the masters went down for a while. With a single master down in a 7-node cluster we noted a marked increase in the average response time for api calls involving redis, which   I would expect.

When the down master was brought back online and re-joined the cluster, we had a massive spike in response time. Via newrelic I can see that the app started making a ton of redis cluster calls (newrelic doesn't tell me which cluster subcommand was being used). Our normal avg response time is around 5ms; during this time it went up to 800ms and we had a few slow sample transactions that took > 70sec. On all app jvms I see the number of active threads jump from a normal 8-9 up to around 300 during this time. We have configured the tomcat http thread pool to allow 400 threads max. After about 3 minutes, the problem cleared itself up, but I now have people questioning the stability of the caching solution we chose. Newrelic doesn't give any insight into where the additional time on the long requests is being spent (it's apparently in an area that Newrelic doesn't instrument).

I've made some attempt to reproduce by running some jmeter load tests against a development environment, and while I see some moderate response time spikes when re-attaching a redis-cluster master, I don't see anything near what we saw in production. I've also run across https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1108, but I'm not gaining any useful insight from that. I tried reducing spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects from the default 5 to 0, which didn't seem to have much effect on my load test results. I'm also not sure how appropriate a change that is for my use case.